# uap10.0 netstandard2.0 disambiguation in nuget

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, nuget, .net-standard-2.0

I'm creating a Nuget package which includes uap10.0 and netstandard2.0 versions of my DLL.

uap10.0 is in fact .netstandard1.3 compatible and can be used for Universal Windows apps on Windows prior to Windows 10 Fall Creators Update. Starting from Windows 10 Fall Creators Update, netstandard2.0 can be used.

I'm wondering how Nuget picks up the version to use. For instance, if I create a UWP project and select Target and Min version as Windows 10 Fall Creators and then use `Install-package MyPackage`, will it pick netstandard2.0 or uap10.0 version of the DLL? Or how am I (the package vendor) supposed to control this?

Comment: Any comments on the reason of downvote? What's wrong with the question?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Thank you for reply, but I still don't understand from that link how this helps. I know that I can use targetFramework to specify dependencies for a particular framework but how does this help in my case when the environment is both uap10.0 and netstandard2.0 compatible. I don't know which one wins. Will nuget pick targetFramework=uap10.0 section or targetFramework= netstandard2.0 if the app is both UAP and netstandard2.0 compatible?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, Please check if my answer helps to clarify this issue. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For instance, if I create a UWP project and select Target and Min
>   version as Windows 10 Fall Creators and then use Install-package
>   MyPackage, will it pick netstandard2.0 or uap10.0 version of the DLL?

In my opinion, it will surely pick the uap10.0 version in a UWP project.

I've done some tests for this to check the result, in a UWP project if we consume the package which includes both `uap10.0 and netstandard2.0` version, it will always pick the `uap10.0` instead of `.netstandard2.0` version. And only when i try to consume a package which only includes `netstandard2.0` version, the UWP will pick the `netstandard2.0` one.

> When NuGet installs a package that has multiple assembly versions, it
>   tries to match the framework name of the assembly with the target
>   framework of the project.

Please check [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks#matching-assembly-versions-and-the-target-framework-in-a-project), so NuGet will use the assembly that is the closest match.(Framework name of assembly<=>target framework name of the project)

So **more specific** target framework wins. As for your situation, within a UWP project which targets uap, it will pick the uap10.0 version from a package which includes several versions. And you don't need to control this, you just need to put different versions of assembly under [corresponding framework folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks#framework-version-folder-structure) before you pack them.

**Update:**

Idea from Alex's reminder. With such structure when creating the nuget package:

```
-lib
  -uap10.0
     --Test.dll
  -uap10.0.16299
     --Test.dll(actually target .net standard2.0)
```

When a UWP project whose min version is 16299 and newer, it will pick the .net standard version which locates in uap10.0.16299 folder. And for those old ones whose min is lower than 16299, it will pick the assembly from uap10.0 folder.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But still, how can I use .netstandard2.0 version of my DLL in a UWP app? I mean if I change Min target in UWP app to "Windows 10 Fall Creators Update", it will still pick uap10.0 version in my package, right? I just see no way to make Nuget pick the more capable .netstandard2.0 version whenever possible (and fall back to uap10.0 version for older Windows targets).

Is it correct that there is no way for Nuget to pick .netstandard2.0 version if uap10.0 version is also present in the package?

Comment: if the above is correct, it seems kinda serious limitation of the current Nuget and UWP. It would require me to create a separate package with .netstandard2.0 with version and no uap10.0 version just to support modern UWP apps. Looks like overkill..

Comment: What if I add uap10.0 and uap10.0.16299 targets in the package (and copy .netstandard2.0 dll in the latter)? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/target-frameworks mentions I can include the minimum Windows build version in uap target. Will this have the effect that for older UAP it will pick generic uap10.0 version and for 16299 and newer (Fall Creators Update) it will effectively pick .netstandard2.0 version?

Comment: @Alex Sorry but there is no way to override the behavior how nuget pick the packages. And to sopport UWP apps with .net standard2.0 version, you need to create a separate package which not includes uap10.0. According to your description, it seems to be a limitation of current nuget rule. And I suggest you can post your idea in [nuget in github](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues).

Comment: @Alex I will check your idea(copy .net standard2.0 dll in the latter), it may take some time:)

Comment: Thanks! "For those whose min version is lower than 16299(Fall Creators Update) it will pick the .net standard." probably you meant quite opposite - NOT lower?

Comment: Yeah, i mean the higher but make some mistake when writing the comment :)